# PRISM Property injection fails

Tags: silverlight, prism

In my Silverlight RIA app I can successfully inject an ExceptionHelper class via constructor injection:

```
[InjectionConstructor]
public CDashCatDataService(IExceptionHelper exceptionHelper)
{
  _exceptionHelper = exceptionHelper;
  SetUp();
}

void SetUp()
{
  if (_context == null)
  {
    try
    {
      throw new Exception("this is a test exception");
      _context = new CDASHDomainContext();          
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      _exceptionHelper.HandleException(ex, string.Format("{0} -> {1}", GetType().FullName, "Setup"));
    }
  }
  Context = _context;
}
```

The SetUp method successfully logs and handles the test exception.

However, I can't get this working if I use property injection instead:

```
[Dependency]
public IExceptionHelper ExceptionHelper { get; set; }
```

and then using

```
catch (Exception ex)
    {
      ExceptionHelper.HandleException(ex, string.Format("{0} -> {1}", GetType().FullName, "Setup"));
    }
```

in the SetUp method. If I use this, the test exception is not logged and handled.

I'm clearly missing something here - any ideas?

Comment: To sort of answer my own question, I think this is because the ExceptionHelper property is being called from the constructor via the SetUp method and you can't call injected properties until after the constructor has executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because the ExceptionHelper property is being called from the constructor via the SetUp method and you can't call injected properties until after the constructor has executed.